# Elapsed time in JNI Crash report meaning

Tags: java, java-native-interface, crash-reports

Below is the sample crash log for java JNI:

```
---------------  S Y S T E M  ---------------

OS: Machine detail...

uname: <uname detail>
library detail
rlimit:
load average:0.18 0.15 0.10

CPU:total 8 (8 cores per cpu, 2 threads per core) 

Memory: 4k page

vm_info: java n gcc info

time: Time stamp
elapsed time: 10000 seconds
```

What does elapsed time signify in this context?

Answer (score 0):

Number of seconds passed since the JVM launch.